# Angular 2 - Error: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, angular

Please take a look on this issue.

**Assumptions**:

I have a component with form to add/edit a test case. Component can be run in 3 different **modes** (first parameter) (0 - empty form, 1 - edit mode, 2 - display mode (no inputs) with selected test case as a second parameter. Second parameter can be an test case object (if mode is 0 and test case object is defined, this object will be a parent of new test case. If mode is 1, selected test case will be edited test case, and when mode is 2 selected test case will be displayed test case. If test case object is undefined, new test case will not have parent object so it will be on the top of the tree).

Form contains 2 fields: name and feature-flag. Feature-flag can be selected from dropdown and add to form. It has a tree structure.

**Reproduction of error**:

When I select a test case, open form to add new or edit test case, add some flags, close form, open new form, over and over for N times, it occours error. I do not have any recuret function calls in my code

**Error text:**

[image]

**Code**:

test-case.component.ts:

```
    /**
     * 
     */
    public ngOnInit() { 
        this.testCasesService.getAll().subscribe(
            records => {
                this.testCases = this.testCasesService.asTree(records, { parent: true, expanded: true })               
            },
            err => {
                console.log(err)
            }
        )
    } 

    /**
     * Opens test case form
     */
    private openTestCaseForm(parent, mode?) {
        if(!parent) 
            this.selectedNode = undefined; 

        if(this.mode != mode) 
            this.mode = mode;

        this.addNewTestCaseForm       = true  
    }
```

test-case.template.html

```
<div style="float: left; width: 100%;">
    <p>
        <p-toolbar>
            <div class="ui-toolbar-group-left">
                <button (click)="openTestCaseForm(false)" pButton type="button" label="New Test Case" icon="fa-plus"></button>
                <button *ngIf="!selectedNode" [disabled]="true" pButton type="button" label="New Child Test Case" icon="fa-plus"></button>
                <button *ngIf="selectedNode" (click)="openTestCaseForm(true)" pButton type="button" label="New Child Test Case" icon="fa-plus"></button>
            </div> 
            <div class="ui-toolbar-group-right">
                <button *ngIf="selectedNode" (click)="openTestCaseForm(true, 1)" pButton type="button" icon="fa-pencil-square-o" label="Edit"></button>
                <button *ngIf="selectedNode" pButton type="button" icon="fa-trash-o" class="ui-button-danger" label="Remove"></button>
            </div>
        </p-toolbar> 
    </p>
</div>
<div style="float: left; width: 35%">
    Search <input placeholder="Search" pInputText type="text" style="border: 1px solid silver" /><br /><br />

    <p-tree [style]="{'font-size':'18px', 'width': '95%'}" selectionMode="single" [(selection)]="selectedNode" [value]="testCases"></p-tree>
</div>
<div style="float: left; width: 65%; border-left: 1px solid silver; padding-left: 20px; font-size: 18px">
    <test-case-editor [testCase]="selectedNode" *ngIf="selectedNode"></test-case-editor>           
</div>

<p-dialog width="1800" modal="true" header="Add New Test Case" [(visible)]="addNewTestCaseForm">
    <test-case-editor [testCase]="selectedNode" [mode]="mode"></test-case-editor>
</p-dialog>
```

test-case-editor.ts (test case form controller)

```
export class TestCaseEditorComponent implements OnInit {
    /**
     * Options for FEATURES flags 
     */
    private featureOptions:any[] = [];

    /**
     * Selected node
     */
    private selectedFeatureNode:any;

    /**
     * Added features (flags)
     */
    private nodes:any[] = [];

    /**
     * Name of test case
     */
    private name:string;

    /**
     * Test case to display/edit
     */
    @Input() public testCase:any;

    /**
     * Mode (0 - new tc, 1 - edit mode, 2 - display mode)
     */
    @Input() public mode:number = 2;

    /**
     * Constructor
     * @param featureFlagsService 
     * @param testCasesService 
     * @param communicatesService 
     */
    constructor(
        private testCasesService:TestCasesService,
        private communicatesService:CommunicatesService,
        private featureFlagsService:FeatureFlagsService) {}

    /**
     * Actions after init
     */
    public ngOnInit() {

    }

    public ngOnChanges() {
        this.init()
    }


    /**
     * Loads flags for particular testCase
     * @param testCase
     */
    public init() {
        this.nodes = []

        this.featureFlagsService.getAll().subscribe(           
            records => {   
                //Creating a tree        
                let tree = this.featureFlagsService.asTree(records, { parent: true })      

                let features      = this.testCasesService.getFeatures(tree)
                let configuration = this.testCasesService.getConfigurationFeatures(tree)

                let featureOptions     = [{ label: 'Select feature...', value: null }]
                featureOptions         = featureOptions.concat(this.testCasesService.getFeaturesOptions(configuration))
                this.featureOptions    = featureOptions.concat(this.testCasesService.getFeaturesOptions(features))

                //Filling form with flags in table when editing
                if(this.testCase && (this.mode == 1 || this.mode == 2)) {
                    this.name = this.testCase.data.name;


                }   
            }                                             
        )          
    }

    /**
     * Adds flag to feature list
     * @param flag 
     */
    private addNode(node) {  
        let found = this.nodes.find(element => {
            if(element.data.id == node.data.id) {
                return true
            }
        })
        if(!found) 
            this.nodes.push(node)
    }
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Why are you banana-boxing non-ngModels?

`[(visible)]="addNewTestCaseForm"`.

This should be a one-way binding:

`[visible]="addNewTestCaseForm"`.

Looks like some syntax issues might be getting in your way.